# Getting static constant to work for navigation

Tags: flutter, dart

I have followed this guide: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-vi-navigation-drawer-flutter-1-0-3a05e09b0db9

trying to replicate the drawer especially. However, I run into an error with the static constant in my Routes.dart file.

the codes looks like this:
in my lib/routes/routes.dart file:

```
import 'package:book_club/main.dart';

class Routes {
  static const String Profile = ProfilePage.routeName;
  static const String BookClub = BookClubPage.routeName;
  static const String Library = LibraryPage.routeName;
  static const String Search = SearchPage.routeName;
  static const String Store = StorePage.routeName;
}
```

It gives me the following two errors:

1. error: Const variables must be initialized with a constant value. (const_initialized_with_non_constant_value at [book_club] lib/Routes/routes.dart:2)
2. error: Undefined name 'ProfilePage'. (undefined_identifier at [book_club] lib/Routes/routes.dart:2)

Anyone who can help me understand what I have done wrong? Tried going through the article several times but cannot find my misstake. I am a complete beginner in programming so hoping that there is an easy and obvious way to fix this :)

Using android studio if that makes a difference.

Comment: please post a [mcve], at least all the identifiers you use.

Answer (score 0):

first import the ProfilePage package,
and

`static const String Profile = ProfilePage.routeName;` here the `routeName` of `ProfilePage` has to be static const as well, which means value of the variable should be known before compiling

```
class AClass{
  static const yadu = '';
}

class BClass{
  static const y = AClass.yadu;
}
```